# making an object move if a variable goes up or down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hi im trying to make a system where a variable controls the position of an object so that if the variable goes up then the Y position of the object will go up and if the variable goes down then the Y position of the object will go down.

I am trying to control the variable from a separate script but the value of the variable is not changing.

the variable script:

```
public class Money : MonoBehaviour {
public static float Flow;
public static float FlowPos;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Flow = 50;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    FlowPos = Flow/100;
    print(Flow);
    transform.position = new Vector3(10.56f,12 + FlowPos,1);
}
```

the script trying to change the variable:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Barista01 : MonoBehaviour {

bool dragging = false;
bool CardActive = true;

void Start(){





}

void Update(){  

    if (transform.position.x > 11.5f && dragging == false){

        GameControllerScript.Active = false;
        this.Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else if (transform.position.x < 4.5f && dragging == false){

        GameControllerScript.Active = false;
        Worker.Morale += 20;
        Money.Flow -= 15;
        this.Destroy(gameObject);

    }

    if (GameControllerScript.CardCall == 2 && CardActive == true){
        CardActive = false;
        Worker.Morale -= 20;
        transform.position = new Vector3(8f, 6.89f, 9f);

    }

}

void OnMouseDown(){
    {
        dragging = true;

    }
}

void OnMouseUp(){
    {
        dragging = false;

    }
}
```

}

edit: I put the plus, minus and eaquals symbols in the correct positions however the variables still do not change

Answer (score 1):

You should correct these two lines:

```
Worker.Morale =+ 20;
Money.Flow =- 15;
```

to

```
Worker.Morale += 20;
Money.Flow -= 15;
```

Comment: The difference between the two is that =+/=- evaluates to x = y (or x = -y), which just assigns a new value, instead of increment it. Correct answer though.

Comment: That's exactly why I suggested the answer, he was assigning always 20 to `Morale` and -15 to `Flow` inside that if statement.

Comment: Yeah its not like i wanted to bash on your answer, i was just trying to add information as to why it needed to be changed, since you did not.

Comment: No bashing taken, I was in a hurry while answering. :)

Comment: I see that OP edited their answer to 'fix' these mistakes, but still expects a different answer i suppose...

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic.